# I can't add an entity when using Jhipster and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, jhipster

I'm trying to add an entity in a jhipster project using ===>

```
jhipster entity <entityName>
```

and when I run my project I have this error ===>

```
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/imen/Bureau/StageSifast2017/EntityTest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/domain/Imen.java:[3,33] package org.hibernate.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /home/imen/Bureau/StageSifast2017/EntityTest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/domain/Imen.java:[4,33] package org.hibernate.annotations does not exist
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.553 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-01T12:04:47+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 52M/478M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) on project entity-test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/imen/Bureau/StageSifast2017/EntityTest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/domain/Imen.java:[3,33] package org.hibernate.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /home/imen/Bureau/StageSifast2017/EntityTest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/domain/Imen.java:[4,33] package org.hibernate.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

[le fichier Imen.java ou se trouve l'erreur dans les import de 
 `import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc87s.png)

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce you issue with JHipster 4.6.2, which version are you using? If you want help you need to post details like output of `jhipster info`.

Comment: I'm working with jhipster 4.6.0

Comment: There was no change related to this code between JH 4.6.0 and 4.6.2 , so it seems to be specific to your project configuration Please post output of `jhipster info` or post a link to a github repo.

Answer (score 0):

````
Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator

##### **JHipster Version(s)**

```
/home/imen
└── (empty)

```

cat: no such file or directory: .yo-rc.json

##### **JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**

```yaml

```


##### **JDL for the Entity configuration(s) `entityName.json` files generated in the `.jhipster` directory**


```yaml





```


##### **Browsers and Operating System**

openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

git version 2.13.0

node: v7.0.0

npm: 5.3.0

bower: 1.8.0

gulp:
[10:11:36] CLI version 1.3.0

yeoman: 2.0.0

yarn: 0.27.5

Execution complete
````